# Unable to rails generate social_stream:install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, social-stream

I want to install social_stream on my new rails project i have installed it on 3.1.0.rc5 Rails but i am not able to get it worked.

here are the error messages which i am seeing on the console when i run command

```
gem 'social_stream'
```

I will be really thankful if any one helps me to get it done.

```
:public is no longer used to avoid overloading Module#public, use :public_folder instead
from /home/baran/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/resque-1.17.1/lib/resque/server.rb:12:in `<class:Server>'
    SECURITY WARNING: No secret option provided to Rack::Session::Cookie.
    This poses a security threat. It is strongly recommended that you
    provide a secret to prevent exploits that may be possible from crafted
    cookies. This will not be supported in future versions of Rack, and
    future versions will even invalidate your existing user cookies.

    Called from: /home/baran/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc5        /lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:28:in `initialize'. /home/baran/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc5/lib/sprockets /ailtie.rb:49:in `asset_environment': undefined method `static_root=' for #<Sprockets::Environment:0x9f647a4> (NoMethodError)
from /home/baran/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc5/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
from /home/baran/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc5/lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:22:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
from /home/baran/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc5/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:34:in `call'
from /home/baran/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc5/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:34:in `execute_hook'
from /home/baran/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc5/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in `block in run_load_hooks'
from /home/baran/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc5/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `each'
from /home/baran/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc5/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `run_load_hooks'
from /home/baran/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc5/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
from /home/baran/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `instance_exec'
from /home/baran/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `run'
from /home/baran/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `block in run_initializers'
from /home/baran/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `each'
from /home/baran/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `run_initializers'
from /home/baran/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc5/lib/rails/application.rb:92:in `initialize!'
from /home/baran/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc5/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
from /home/baran/RubymineProjects/bktest1/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/baran/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:237:in `require'
from /home/baran/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:237:in `block in require'
from /home/baran/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load_dependency'
from /home/baran/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:639:in `new_constants_in'
from /home/baran/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
from /home/baran/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:237:in `require'
from /home/baran/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc5/lib/rails/application.rb:78:in `require_environment!'
from /home/baran/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc5/lib/rails/commands.rb:22:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

here is the gem list:

```
actionmailer (4.0.0, 3.2.14, 3.1.0.rc8, 3.1.0.rc5)
actionpack (4.0.0, 3.2.14, 3.1.0.rc8, 3.1.0.rc5)
activemodel (4.0.0, 3.2.14, 3.1.0.rc8, 3.1.0.rc5)
activerecord (4.0.0, 3.2.14, 3.1.0.rc8, 3.1.0.rc5)
activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
activerecord-mysql2-adapter (0.0.3)
activeresource (3.2.14, 3.1.0.rc8, 3.1.0.rc5)
activesupport (4.0.0, 3.2.14, 3.1.0.rc8, 3.1.0.rc5)
acts-as-taggable-on (2.0.6)
acts_as_commentable (3.0.1)
addressable (2.3.5, 2.2.4)
ancestry (1.2.5)
ansi (1.4.3)
arel (4.0.0, 3.0.2, 2.2.3, 2.1.4)
atomic (1.1.13)
authlogic (3.3.0)
avatars_for_rails (0.1.6)
aws-s3 (0.6.3)
babosa (0.3.11)
bborn-acts-as-taggable-on (2.2.1)
bcrypt-ruby (3.1.2, 3.0.1, 2.1.4)
builder (3.1.4, 3.0.4)
bundler (1.3.5)
bundler-unload (1.0.1)
cancan (1.6.10)
cocaine (0.3.2)
coffee-rails (4.0.0, 3.2.2, 3.1.0)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.6.3)
community_engine (2.3.0)
configatron (2.13.0)
devise (1.3.4)
dynamic_form (1.1.4)
erubis (2.7.0)
execjs (2.0.1)
faraday (0.8.8, 0.6.1)
foreigner (0.9.2)
formtastic (1.2.4)
friendly_id (3.3.3.0)
haml (4.0.3)
has_scope (0.5.1)
hashie (2.0.5)
hike (1.2.3)
hpricot (0.8.6)
htmlentities (4.3.1)
i18n (0.6.5)
inherited_resources (1.2.2)
jbuilder (1.5.1)
journey (1.0.4)
jquery-rails (3.0.4, 1.0.19)
json (1.8.0, 1.5.5)
kaminari (0.14.1, 0.12.4)
koala (1.6.0)
mail (2.5.4, 2.3.3)
mailboxer (0.5.1)
meta_search (1.1.3)
mime-types (1.25)
mini_portile (0.5.1)
minitest (4.7.5)
modernizr-rails (2.0.6)
multi_json (1.7.9, 1.0.4)
multi_xml (0.2.2)
multipart-post (1.2.0, 1.1.5)
mysql2 (0.3.13)
net-ldap (0.2.2)
nokogiri (1.6.0, 1.4.7)
oa-basic (0.2.6)
oa-core (0.2.6)
oa-enterprise (0.2.6)
oa-more (0.2.6)
oa-oauth (0.2.6)
oa-openid (0.2.6)
oauth (0.4.7)
oauth-plugin (0.4.0.rc2)
oauth2 (0.4.1)
omniauth (1.1.4, 0.2.6)
orm_adapter (0.0.7)
paperclip (2.4.5, 2.3.11)
paperclip-ffmpeg (0.7.0)
polyamorous (0.5.0)
polyglot (0.3.3)
prototype-rails (3.2.1)
pyu-ruby-sasl (0.0.3.3)
rack (1.5.2, 1.4.5, 1.3.10)
rack-cache (1.2, 1.0.3)
rack-mount (0.8.3)
rack-openid (1.3.1)
rack-protection (1.5.0)
rack-ssl (1.3.3)
rack-test (0.6.2)
rails (4.0.0, 3.2.14, 3.1.0.rc8, 3.1.0.rc5)
rails_autolink (1.1.0)
railties (4.0.0, 3.2.14, 3.1.0.rc8, 3.1.0.rc5)
rake (10.1.0)
rakismet (1.3.0)
rdoc (3.12.2)
recaptcha (0.3.5)
redis (2.2.2)
redis-namespace (1.0.4)
responders (0.6.5)
resque (1.17.1)
rest-client (1.6.7)
ri_cal (0.8.8)
rmagick (2.13.2)
ruby-openid (2.2.3)    
ruby-openid-apps-discovery (1.2.0)
rubygems-bundler (1.2.2)
rubyntlm (0.1.1)
rvm (1.11.3.8)
sanitize (2.0.6)
sass (3.2.10)
sass-rails (4.0.0, 3.2.6, 3.1.0.rc.5)
sdoc (0.3.20)
simple-navigation (3.11.0)
sinatra (1.3.3)
social_stream (0.7.8)
social_stream-base (0.7.11)
social_stream-documents (0.2.4)    
social_stream-events (0.0.1)
sprockets (2.10.0, 2.2.2, 2.0.4)
sprockets-rails (2.0.0)
sqlite3 (1.3.8)
stringex (1.2.2)
thor (0.18.1, 0.14.6)
thread_safe (0.1.2)
tilt (1.4.1)
tinymce-rails (3.5.8.3)
treetop (1.4.15)
turbolinks (1.3.0)
turn (0.9.6)
tzinfo (0.3.37)
uglifier (2.2.1)
vegas (0.1.11)
warden (1.0.6)
xml-simple (1.1.2)
yamler (0.1.0)
```

Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is an issue with the resque gem.  Try updating resque or using the following in your gemfile:

```
gem "resque", "~> 2.0.0.pre.1", github: "resque/resque"
```

Comment: this does not work as there is conflict of thor with the rails version of the social stream gem.
In Gemfile:
    resque (~> 2.0.0.pre.1) ruby depends on
      thor (~> 0.17) ruby

    rails (= 3.1.0.rc5) ruby depends on
      thor (0.14.6)

Answer (score 0):

There was error in the manual installation. I just get the way to install from the wiki and i get it installed. Following is the link.

https://github.com/ging/social_stream/wiki/SETUP-TIPS-FOR-DUMMIES